# How to kill all processes from list in csv file

Tags: java, linux, shell, pid

I would like to write a shell script that kills all the PID stored in a txt file as follows:

```
83738 //delimiter is \n
394380
30984
...
```

Basically, I start these from java and store the pid in this file in case something goes wrong on the main thread. I want to avoid killing them one by one (without knowing on which java is my IDE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the file is called pids.txt you can use:

```
xargs kill < pids.txt
```

`xargs` is a program that reads text from standard input, and passes them as command line arguments to another program.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done like so:

```sh
while read -r pid; do 
  kill $pid; 
done < pid.txt
```